Download Excel file with Graphql Springboot API
I am trying to download an excel file with the API written in GraphQL springboot.
I am able to create the excel file from the database. Now , I want to return it to the user when the user hits the API. I want to download it and not save it.
Below is my resolver code -
@QueryMapping(DOWNLOAD_EXCEL)
public ResponseEntity downloadExcel (@Argument ("type") FileType type , @Argument ("input") ERequest request){
String fileName= "data.xlsx";
ByteArrayInputStream exelData = service.downloadExcel(type, request);
InputStreamResource file= new InputStreamResource(exelData);
ResponseEntity body=  ResponseEntity.ok()
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename = " +fileName)
.contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel")).body(file);
return body;
}
Below is my graphql.schema
DownloadExcel(type: FileType, input: Request): BinaryData @auth(permissions:"DtvServices:Read")
scalar BinaryData
I have also implemented scalar BinaryData
Below is my GraphQLConfiguration
@Bean
public GraphQL getGraphQL(CommonConfiguration config) {
InputStream schemaStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.graphqls");
TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(Objects.requireNonNull(Utility.getFile(config.getGraphQlSchemaConfig())));
var wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
return GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
}
private RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .directive(SECURED_DIRECTIVE, new AuthDirectiveWiring(permissionConfiguration))
            .scalar(GraphQLScalarType.newScalar().name("BinaryData").coercing(new BinaryDataCoercing()).build())
            .build();
}

It still gives me the error
errors=[There is no scalar implementation for the named  'BinaryData' scalar type]
Any help on this would be highly valuable. I am stuck on this for a week now.
Thanks

Please format your code more clearly
